# Как сделать так, чтобы границы блоков не накладывались друг на друга?

Tags: html, css

Есть два блока, один под  находится под другим. У обоих граница `top` и `bottom`.

Выходит так, что верхняя граница нижнего блока залезает на нижнюю границу верхнего блока. Можно ли как-нибудь сделать так, чтобы не было заметно "двойной" границы. Своего рода аналог `border-collapse: collapse;` у таблиц.

Comment: Пожалуйста, редактируйте свой вопрос, добавив в него пример кода, в котором есть указанная проблема, чтобы пользователи смогли дать лаконичный ответ. В противном случае, вопрос может быть закрыт проверяющими. Чтобы редактировать вопрос, нажмите на кнопку [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как задать хороший вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

```css
.cell {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.cell + .cell {margin: -3px 0;}
```

```html
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
```

Comment: а зачем такой мудрёный селектор? `.cell + .cell` будет быстрее.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, что значит быстрее?) Я не подумал про `+`, но уже поздно

Comment: насколько мне известно, селектор `*` — один из самых медленных, я об этом ) хотя может уже мои данные устарели и в самых современных браузерах с этим гораздо лучше.

Comment: Вот тест нагуглил, но тут нет `+` https://benfrain.com/selector-test/13.html

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, спасибо вам за правку :) Я внёс её в ответ

Answer (score 1):

Можно поигратся с `margin`. Например:

```css
#a {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin: -2px 0 -2px 0px;
}

#b {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">

</div>

<div id="b">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 2em;
}

div:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```